# Writing my own IsDate function in VB

Tags: vb.net, validation, datetime

I have had problems with VB.NET IsDate function - it returns true on string values that are not a valid date, such as "367 7" and "10,600" etc. So I have decided to write my own function and wanted to hear some feedback on possible improvements. Would really appreciate valuable input.

```
Function IsValidDate(ByVal str As String) As Boolean
    str = str.Replace(" ", "").Trim()
    'If (str Is Nothing) Then
     '   Return False
    'End If
    'If IsNumeric(str) Then
    '    Return False
    'End If
    'If Regex.IsMatch(str, "^[A-Za-z ]+$") Then
    '    Return False
    'End If
    If Regex.IsMatch(str, "^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$") Then
        ''mm/dd/yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy
        Return True
    ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(str, "^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.]\d\d$") Then
        ''mm/dd/yy or mm-dd-yy
        Return True
    ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(str, "^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$") Then
        ''dd-mm-yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy
        Return True
    ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(str, "^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$") Then
        ''yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy/mm/dd

        Return True
    End If

    Return False
End Function
```

I took care of a possible space in the numeric string (ex.: "367 7", then I made sure it returns false if the value is numeric or nothing. I also eliminated strings that are all alphanumeric. Please let me know what do you think. Thank you

P.S> Edit: I commented out a few lines in the beginning as I felt they could be eliminated since if the string does not match one of the regexes, it will return false anyway

Comment: You disallow a few formats that some people might expect to be valid. Not a problem if you are the only user, but something to consider if others may use the function. You are not allowing formats where " " is the delimiter (e.g. 12 31 2014), and you are not allowing the month to be spelled out (either in full or abbreviated - e.g. Apr or April).

Comment: This is not a question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running into this situation in my own code, I found that the 'TryParseExact' function is significantly slower than using a series of 'Regex.Match' calls.

This is the function that I wrote to check the formats I am looking for and it ran about 10x faster than TryParseExact.

The downside of this over TryParseExact is that it does not check all of the edge cases, such as '31 is not a valid day in November' or '29 is not a valid day in Feb on certain years'. So as long as you are willing to give up those catches, then this is faster.

```
        Public Shared Function ChkDate(ByVal Value As Object) As Boolean
            If Value.GetType().Name = "DateTime" Then
                Return True
            ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Value.ToString()) Then
                Dim TempStr As String = Value.ToString()
                ' Please speed test before making any changes to this function, the below version is much faster than Date.TryParse or Date.TryParseExact

                If InStr(TempStr, ".") <> 0 AndAlso TempStr.Split({"."c}).Length = 3 Then ' d.M.yyyy
                    Dim TempArray() As String = TempStr.Split({"."c})
                    Dim NewString As String = TempArray(1) & "/" & TempArray(0) & "/" & TempArray(2)
                ElseIf InStr(TempStr, "/") <> 0 AndAlso RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TempStr, "\A[01]{0,1}[0-9]{1}/[0123]{0,1}[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{4}\z") Then ' M/d/yyyy
                    Return True
                ElseIf InStr(TempStr, "-") <> 0 AndAlso RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TempStr, "\A[0-9]{4}-[01]{0,1}[0-9]{1}-[0123]{0,1}[0-9]{1}\z") Then ' yyyy-M-d
                    Return True
                ElseIf InStr(TempStr, "-") <> 0 AndAlso InStr(TempStr, ":") <> 0 AndAlso RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TempStr, "\A[0-9]{4}-[01]{0,1}[0-9]{1}-[0123]{0,1}[0-9]{1} [01]{0,1}[0-9]{1}:[01]{0,1}[0-6]{1}:[01]{0,1}[0-6]{1}\z") Then ' yyyy-M-d H:mm:ss
                    Return True
                ElseIf InStr(TempStr, "/") <> 0 AndAlso InStr(TempStr, ":") <> 0 AndAlso RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TempStr, "\A[01]{0,1}[0-9]{1}/[0123]{0,1}[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{4} [01]{0,1}[0-9]{1}:[01]{0,1}[0-6]{1}\z") Then ' M/d/yyyy h:mm
                    Return True
                ElseIf RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TempStr, "\A[0-9]{4}[01]{1}[0-9]{1}[0123]{1}[0-9]{1}\z") Then ' yyyyMMdd
                    Return True
                ElseIf RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TempStr, "\A[0-9]{4}[01]{0,1}[0-9]{1}[0123]{0,1}[0-9]{1}[01]{0,1}[0-9]{1}[01]{0,1}[0-6]{1}\z") Then ' yyyyMMddHHmm
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return IsDate(TempStr)
                End If
            End If
            Return False
        End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Have tried something like this?

```
   Function IsValidDate(ByVal str As String) As Boolean
Dim test As Date
        If Date.TryParseExact(str, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, test) Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
    End Function
```

From here you can just change the format in the quotes.

**!EDIT!**

I can't add comments because of my reputation, but if have your array of formats like in your comment and use my code, instead of the format I have in there, put your array formats in its' place. It worked fine for me.

```
Dim test As Date
Dim formats As String() = {"MM/dd/yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "MM/dd/yy", "MM-dd-yy", "M-d-yyyy", "M/d/yyyy", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", _
                               "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"}



If Date.TryParseExact(str, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, test) Then
   Return True
Else
   Return False
End If
```

This won't reorganize your input, but rather just a Boolean return to see if it matches the format you specify, which is what you originally wanted correct?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the Regexes, have you looked at [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx)? It lets you define the exact formats you support.

Comment: Hans, I tried ParseExact and if the string in question is not a valid datetime, it throws an exception. Not sure if that's the best way to handle things... Am I doing something wrong here?   Dim formats As String() = {"MM/dd/yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "MM/dd/yy", "MM-dd-yy", "M-d-yyyy", "M/d/yyyy", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", _
 "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"}
        dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, formats, New CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None)

Comment: @ElenaDBA If you want to avoid the exceptions you can just use [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. Which one is most suitable would depend on the circumstances, if the input is from another application or stored data, I would probably stick with throwing exceptions, though if you want to check if user input is a valid date, then in some cases I might go for the one that returns false instead.